# Problem installing sf package in macOS Catalina (10.15.6)

Tags: macos, r-sf

I have tried multiple ways to install sf package using Rstudio (2022.07.01) and R version R-4.2.1 (both latest versions). When I am trying to install the "sf" package, I get the following error message:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sf’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/sf/libs/sf.so':
dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/sf/libs/sf.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/netcdf/lib/libnetcdf.18.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/gdal/lib/libgdal.27.dylib
Reason: image not found
```

This error also occurs when I try to load some other packages.

While trying to install the package, the first error that occurs during compilation is:

```
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/gdal/lib/libgdal.27.dylib
  Reason: image not found
./configure: line 3625: 15042 Abort trap: 6           ./gdal_proj
no
```

I have tried many ways, re-istalling R and R-studio, installing but without any success. Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

this problem was apparently caused by Your manual install of `gdal` not correctly linking to geos.

So try to reinstalled `gdal` following these instructions (https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingOnUnix) with --with-geos=yes as a flag to ./configure.

This solved the problem.

Comment: @user18710300 thanks for your response. i have GDAL 3.5.1. I am using "brew install gdal" to re-install  but it fails. Also,  I can not find configure folder in the already installed version. How can I unistall the current gdal? and what command are you using to re-install?Also, when I type "install.packages("gdal")" , I get  ‘gdal’ is not available for this version of R"